# Django across joint filter ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, orm

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def get_all():
        return Question.objects.all()
    def get_detail(question_id):
        return Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
from .models import Question, Choice

def DetailView(request, question_id):
    q = Question.get_detail(question_id)
    choices = Choice.objects.filter(question__question_text = q.question_text)  
    #I also try question__pk == question_id
    context = {"qs":q, "choices":choices}
    return render(request, "detail_question.html", context)
```

My url:

```
path('detail/<int:question_id>', views.DetailView, name = 'detail'),
```

My templates:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content123 %}
        {% if qs %}
        <h1>{{ qs.question_text }}</h1>
        <form action="">
            <ul>
            {% for choice in choices %}
            <li><input type="radio" value="{{ qs.id }}" name="choice">{{ choice.choice_text }}<li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit"</p>
        </form>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I try to make a page in which it will display the question and the related vote.
I have succeed with ManyToOne relationship with question.choice_set_all in the template.

But this does not render the choice only the Question
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk1dq.png)

Comment: Did you execute this command `Python manage.py makemigrations` ?

Comment: You're passing "qs", not "Questions". And shown template seems to stand for ListView, not DetailView.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks I copy wrong template. The right template is {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content123 %}
  {% if qs %}
  <h1>{{ qs.question_text }}</h1>
  <form action="">
   <ul>
   {% for choice in choices %}
   <li><input type="radio" value="{{ qs.id }}" name="choice">{{ choice.choice_text }}<li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit"</p>
  </form>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam I forgot to executing that command. Thank you. However it does not render the vote, onyly the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this at all. `question` is already the accessor for the related questions, you don't need to compare the text. Just do `q.choice_set.all()`.

Comment: Hello
It does not work also 
normally does q.choice_set.all() work only for Foreignerkey?